# How to import GEOMETRY TYPE data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, workbench, sqlgeometry

I am trying to import CSV data into MySQL using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE syntax. In this case the data includes a geometry field that is tripping me up.

An error occurs when MYSQL WORKBENCH loads GEOMETRY TYPE data.
Error messages :

> Row import failed with error: ('Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field', 1416)

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

table name safety_gis

```
FID varchar(200)    NO  PRI     
OBJT_ID int(11) YES         
TY_NM   varchar(100)    YES         
TY_CD   varchar(20) YES         
GRAD    int(11) YES         
CTPRVN_CD   varchar(10) YES         
SGG_CD  varchar(10) YES         
AG_GEOM geometry    YES
```

load_file

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ubuntu/load_test/test.csv'
INTO TABLE safety_gis
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ','  
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4, @col5 , @col6 , @col7 , @col8 )
SET
`FID` = @col1,
`OBJT_ID` = @col2,
`TY_NM` = @col3,
`TY_CD` = @col4,
`GRAD` = @col5,
`CTPRVN_CD` = @col6,
`SGG_CD` = @col7,
`AG_GEOM` = ST_PolygonFromText(@col8);
```

test_csv

```
FID,OBJT_ID,TY_NM,TY_CD,GRAD,CTPRVN_CD,SGG_CD,AG_GEOM
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6911,1,보행어린이사고,20401000,5,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14139310.3745 4519853.5273, 14139304.2634 4519855.4706, 14139279.3515 4519845.895, 14139281.7462 4519839.2989, 14139281.5786 4519815.0892, 14139281.6152 4519814.3426, 14139313.2214 4519809.4934, 14139308.9802 4519845.1538, 14139310.4433 4519852.772, 14139310.3745 4519853.5273)), ((14139332.263 4519671.377, 14139299.7047 4519673.9831, 14139303.2268 4519650.3649, 14139304.9583 4519633.5626, 14139336.6786 4519631.0236, 14139336.7398 4519631.1, 14139336.4054 4519637.856, 14139334.7447 4519655.1687, 14139332.263 4519671.377)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6912,2,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"POLYGON((14135987.3659 4519812.2098, 14135975.3897 4519839.6573, 14135973.7272 4519844.6736, 14135967.7032 4519843.305, 14135969.6058 4519837.8341, 14135966.5689 4519835.9986, 14135982.3256 4519809.6779, 14135987.3659 4519812.2098))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6913,3,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14139166.3176 4519813.5337, 14139163.8883 4519813.4372, 14139154.3365 4519816.9317, 14139149.1959 4519819.3854, 14139147.0576 4519812.2832, 14139162.8034 4519805.9835, 14139164.8922 4519805.471, 14139166.3176 4519813.5337)), ((14139207.9957 4519577.1199, 14139203.0703 4519586.3209, 14139203.9154 4519590.3071, 14139189.2007 4519617.2521, 14139191.1418 4519619.3272, 14139184.5016 4519625.795, 14139182.6743 4519625.2763, 14139181.4518 4519626.1245, 14139165.8556 4519656.1956, 14139161.2984 4519653.6197, 14139186.9177 4519603.3699, 14139181.341 4519600.0844, 14139188.6073 4519593.824, 14139192.0202 4519595.4215, 14139196.2727 4519587.2199, 14139207.9957 4519577.1199)), ((14139264.7363 4519576.2651, 14139251.7079 4519577.0984, 14139251.6881 4519577.1168, 14139249.9727 4519576.8982, 14139249.0272 4519576.0124, 14139222.8553 4519564.3175, 14139227.145 4519560.6216, 14139236.5372 4519564.8489, 14139241.7166 4519566.2437, 14139258.1127 4519573.6318, 14139275.0141 4519542.0304, 14139284.6359 4519539.4885, 14139279.1916 4519549.8496, 14139304.9501 4519554.0468, 14139308.2138 4519554.16, 14139309.7764 4519553.2487, 14139309.4498 4519560.3419, 14139302.4787 4519560.1708, 14139279.5452 4519554.7344, 14139275.9161 4519555.6461, 14139269.2514 4519565.4294, 14139265.3588 4519573.466, 14139264.7363 4519576.2651)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6914,4,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"POLYGON((14134245.5369 4524027.1728, 14134245.5426 4524027.0814, 14134254.1143 4524030.4389, 14134245.5369 4524027.1728))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6915,5,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14132651.4119 4524459.618, 14132650.152 4524468.9761, 14132646.1495 4524481.6984, 14132641.3146 4524494.2811, 14132634.6575 4524495.2782, 14132632.8155 4524497.8728, 14132622.9567 4524508.9385, 14132615.8653 4524508.3687, 14132620.786 4524501.6653, 14132622.1491 4524498.7034, 14132627.6093 4524496.5156, 14132635.5194 4524485.6308, 14132637.2104 4524482.0233, 14132642.6518 4524466.3263, 14132643.2139 4524458.9593, 14132651.4119 4524459.618)), ((14132610.7099 4524456.3475, 14132604.8918 4524466.5869, 14132603.1769 4524466.9407, 14132599.5431 4524473.434, 14132594.8668 4524470.5197, 14132598.6019 4524464.0138, 14132598.7289 4524462.254, 14132602.4245 4524455.6817, 14132610.7099 4524456.3475)), ((14132730.5304 4524438.9816, 14132729.7224 4524460.3533, 14132727.9209 4524457.3266, 14132719.0874 4524447.8268, 14132714.3011 4524438.139, 14132713.8018 4524436.6897, 14132721.7515 4524433.1423, 14132722.0565 4524433.9773, 14132724.3992 4524438.9541, 14132730.5304 4524438.9816)), ((14132508.5652 4524369.7152, 14132514.1703 4524383.3733, 14132502.663 4524375.962, 14132501.0502 4524373.8721, 14132499.9931 4524369.5796, 14132500.0099 4524361.4134, 14132498.0211 4524354.5375, 14132494.4693 4524347.6357, 14132492.5668 4524345.1153, 14132490.3235 4524343.215, 14132491.8815 4524340.8708, 14132495.5072 4524339.9773, 14132497.5925 4524342.9773, 14132504.5574 4524359.9491, 14132505.6811 4524365.5942, 14132508.3521 4524369.5329, 14132508.5652 4524369.7152)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6916,6,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14136381.2505 4520091.3595, 14136381.1716 4520092.253, 14136380.9944 4520099.935, 14136382.5174 4520115.7673, 14136387.8851 4520124.2727, 14136388.4015 4520127.1707, 14136388.4161 4520140.1805, 14136372.1371 4520138.8726, 14136369.2218 4520116.2214, 14136367.1223 4520094.5056, 14136381.2505 4520091.3595)), ((14136496.5786 4519934.1215, 14136496.2597 4519934.1973, 14136496.1103 4519933.578, 14136496.5786 4519934.1215)), ((14136424.565 4519876.7736, 14136432.4223 4519880.2796, 14136466.6389 4519899.3708, 14136482.0723 4519917.2842, 14136449.9369 4519909.5269, 14136420.5105 4519914.2566, 14136398.6798 4519913.6163, 14136396.6786 4519911.0236, 14136373.5413 4519913.2319, 14136373.5426 4519913.2009, 14136328.9563 4519912.0061, 14136323.9404 4519913.9671, 14136310.2547 4519913.8262, 14136310.2797 4519915.2185, 14136302.0379 4519915.2808, 14136302.0383 4519911.2943, 14136272.405 4519910.5516, 14136314.8685 4519873.9674, 14136351.9343 4519874.6247, 14136424.565 4519876.7736)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6917,7,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"POLYGON((14136397.118 4519861.5336, 14136394.7702 4519862.2654, 14136394.1401 4519862.9107, 14136393.9746 4519875.7813, 14136383.2378 4519875.5396, 14136383.0027 4519862.4186, 14136396.6786 4519861.0236, 14136397.118 4519861.5336))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6918,8,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"POLYGON((14133510.1624 4522294.1791, 14133509.3359 4522294.2352, 14133508.9018 4522290.6643, 14133507.9861 4522288.66, 14133506.1074 4522287.0326, 14133481.205 4522274.0862, 14133475.3356 4522262.565, 14133471.165 4522258.5379, 14133461.0826 4522254.5719, 14133457.3727 4522252.5336, 14133462.6477 4522247.8205, 14133466.1084 4522247.5703, 14133480.2086 4522256.5351, 14133482.0227 4522258.9637, 14133484.5477 4522267.733, 14133485.4803 4522268.5815, 14133510.9871 4522282.7941, 14133511.3401 4522282.5411, 14133510.1624 4522294.1791))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6919,9,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"POLYGON((14133969.3766 4520860.4608, 14133940.7221 4520868.9007, 14133926.0161 4520874.4898, 14133914.703 4520879.9429, 14133913.604 4520875.559, 14133924.2783 4520870.4138, 14133939.3195 4520864.6982, 14133968.4222 4520856.1259, 14133968.8959 4520856.0314, 14133969.3766 4520860.4608))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_691a,10,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14139366.2441 4519922.122, 14139361.1795 4519923.6469, 14139363.2674 4519898.2263, 14139368.54 4519894.8215, 14139366.2441 4519922.122)), ((14139435.4858 4519864.3315, 14139419.1129 4519884.1252, 14139425.7425 4519870.0268, 14139426.8003 4519865.1923, 14139425.4134 4519861.4718, 14139415.1183 4519860.5569, 14139419.6322 4519853.9972, 14139432.507 4519854.8899, 14139434.3971 4519853.548, 14139437.14 4519829.2997, 14139437.3774 4519828.2094, 14139438.7782 4519826.1737, 14139459.4572 4519747.2566, 14139456.6613 4519763.0331, 14139455.452 4519764.8682, 14139442.9365 4519825.5022, 14139435.4858 4519864.3315)), ((14139459.7607 4519668.0465, 14139459.7712 4519676.4581, 14139461.6205 4519728.7364, 14139460.9153 4519731.2422, 14139460.5305 4519736.153, 14139455.6042 4519718.9074, 14139453.9989 4519648.9093, 14139459.7607 4519668.0465)), ((14139451.0655 4519639.1664, 14139430.3518 4519638.1182, 14139429.7709 4519644.3606, 14139422.4299 4519636.4377, 14139420.9877 4519633.3615, 14139413.5892 4519626.8834, 14139413.5515 4519626.8555, 14139384.5415 4519595.5462, 14139390.8759 4519597.1858, 14139391.9607 4519603.2728, 14139411.2939 4519615.064, 14139412.5168 4519618.4427, 14139428.9511 4519628.3361, 14139436.3209 4519615.5151, 14139438.5268 4519619.1974, 14139434.9497 4519628.5755, 14139432.1019 4519630.4236, 14139449.3284 4519633.3967, 14139451.0655 4519639.1664)), ((14139370.0845 4519551.0814, 14139357.8621 4519579.2222, 14139353.8741 4519577.3401, 14139356.3805 4519571.2994, 14139366.0566 4519549.8687, 14139370.0845 4519551.0814)), ((14139353.755 4519546.1649, 14139351.7139 4519548.129, 14139347.0265 4519550.6355, 14139339.6677 4519553.4968, 14139338.7971 4519547.4983, 14139340.158 4519547.5613, 14139349.0546 4519545.244, 14139349.4452 4519544.8673, 14139353.755 4519546.1649)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_691b,11,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14132747.3928 4524472.3388, 14132746.7709 4524479.5597, 14132743.5373 4524482.3456, 14132730.0221 4524488.3763, 14132730.0246 4524488.2708, 14132731.5104 4524465.5073, 14132729.7224 4524460.3533, 14132730.6652 4524438.9822, 14132730.5304 4524438.9816, 14132731.0191 4524426.0574, 14132752.0466 4524396.401, 14132750.5095 4524411.5046, 14132749.7694 4524430.5464, 14132750.8643 4524434.8135, 14132752.1051 4524451.0073, 14132747.3928 4524472.3388)), ((14132490.3235 4524343.215, 14132483.3893 4524343.5915, 14132479.7322 4524345.1977, 14132467.6002 4524352.9907, 14132464.549 4524353.3818, 14132462.1158 4524353.1274, 14132455.8506 4524351.9849, 14132451.8996 4524350.7233, 14132449.0053 4524351.4365, 14132447.8073 4524338.4445, 14132477.5346 4524331.188, 14132472.3406 4524326.8613, 14132470.6272 4524324.6702, 14132467.303 4524318.4981, 14132446.4255 4524323.459, 14132445.3366 4524311.6492, 14132448.4068 4524311.2134, 14132456.9677 4524310.2302, 14132460.4347 4524310.2826, 14132465.0631 4524307.4236, 14132462.7515 4524305.3271, 14132489.9599 4524299.0392, 14132490.3889 4524286.3178, 14132491.6929 4524275.1391, 14132494.5503 4524257.922, 14132495.8941 4524242.9579, 14132494.4848 4524237.3484, 14132489.874 4524229.9398, 14132480.4223 4524207.2368, 14132485.6824 4524197.8091, 14132492.7613 4524203.5057, 14132494.3102 4524207.1401, 14132491.7213 4524216.5836, 14132502.0835 4524244.2902, 14132496.6977 4524275.8379, 14132495.1146 4524290.4348, 14132495.0138 4524297.8713, 14132501.0832 4524296.4685, 14132496.9845 4524311.4442, 14132494.8223 4524311.9581, 14132494.5433 4524320.3643, 14132492.0505 4524329.4727, 14132496.2829 4524339.7861, 14132495.5072 4524339.9773, 14132493.9572 4524337.7474, 14132491.8815 4524340.8708, 14132490.3235 4524343.215), (14132469.4927 4524346.388, 14132459.8803 4524348.7566, 14132464.9414 4524349.7862, 14132469.4927 4524346.388), (14132474.6123 4524322.1652, 14132483.6407 4524329.6972, 14132489.2298 4524328.3328, 14132489.7467 4524313.1644, 14132471.7002 4524317.453, 14132474.6123 4524322.1652)), ((14132798.182 4524272.1772, 14132797.422 4524273.2076, 14132774.5083 4524315.8064, 14132776.0224 4524296.9635, 14132748.6865 4524235.7025, 14132771.7128 4524224.3637, 14132783.2136 4524217.6208, 14132794.1282 4524208.9691, 14132817.0228 4524245.5217, 14132810.7436 4524255.1471, 14132805.9655 4524261.6249, 14132806.0004 4524261.5004, 14132798.2421 4524272.056, 14132798.182 4524272.1772)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_691c,12,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"POLYGON((14132462.7515 4524305.3271, 14132465.0631 4524307.4236, 14132460.4347 4524310.2826, 14132456.9677 4524310.2302, 14132448.4068 4524311.2134, 14132445.3366 4524311.6492, 14132445.1291 4524309.3997, 14132462.7515 4524305.3271))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_691d,13,보행어린이사고,20401000,3,11,11110,"POLYGON((14136366.8052 4520091.2263, 14136354.4782 4520091.9521, 14136340.0823 4520086.2928, 14136353.611 4520086.9344, 14136364.6759 4520086.2775, 14136366.8052 4520091.2263))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_691e,14,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"POLYGON((14133835.4144 4523853.6639, 14133831.4582 4523866.0536, 14133840.1554 4523870.4879, 14133839.9788 4523870.855, 14133843.9493 4523872.9833, 14133857.17 4523883.7112, 14133870.617 4523896.5536, 14133871.1085 4523896.919, 14133867.9012 4523899.8908, 14133867.8045 4523899.8188, 14133849.3924 4523881.2523, 14133842.4229 4523875.5401, 14133832.4275 4523870.1052, 14133830.7129 4523870.6364, 14133828.5514 4523886.9672, 14133827.2082 4523905.4633, 14133824.3812 4523914.6284, 14133843.1398 4523922.8334, 14133839.3505 4523926.3443, 14133820.9257 4523917.8049, 14133819.5273 4523914.7405, 14133819.6419 4523911.9173, 14133821.6742 4523904.3853, 14133822.3067 4523898.5113, 14133824.2897 4523888.2317, 14133825.416 4523876.2429, 14133829.1437 4523859.4741, 14133835.4144 4523853.6639))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_691f,15,보행어린이사고,20401000,3,11,11110,"POLYGON((14135481.0687 4520251.814, 14135473.8992 4520253.3243, 14135473.8344 4520253.2046, 14135481.0687 4520251.814))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6920,16,보행어린이사고,20401000,3,11,11110,"POLYGON((14134088.736 4520383.3285, 14134084.7004 4520391.832, 14134082.0773 4520424.9394, 14134062.673 4520417.3112, 14134064.0784 4520403.823, 14134065.9734 4520389.9399, 14134065.6468 4520386.8645, 14134069.5891 4520355.6815, 14134072.9486 4520334.2181, 14134079.1441 4520273.4082, 14134080.2296 4520268.9284, 14134082.6608 4520243.281, 14134101.4269 4520242.0357, 14134097.4783 4520280.9828, 14134091.9688 4520325.3526, 14134087.2493 4520343.9806, 14134085.2792 4520356.2082, 14134088.736 4520383.3285))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6921,17,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14133862.7019 4523821.2001, 14133860.2171 4523830.683, 14133840.7704 4523848.7014, 14133838.8272 4523847.5092, 14133833.1675 4523845.4309, 14133800.6772 4523827.0676, 14133817.7506 4523795.6485, 14133825.1154 4523799.7502, 14133862.7019 4523821.2001)), ((14133661.289 4523822.4866, 14133652.1136 4523831.0328, 14133633.4328 4523847.5206, 14133628.4379 4523842.1299, 14133627.4784 4523840.0966, 14133657.0366 4523813.6397, 14133662.523 4523807.2231, 14133665.0403 4523803.8075, 14133670.1965 4523813.9442, 14133669.681 4523814.6701, 14133661.1937 4523822.3895, 14133661.289 4523822.4866)), ((14133660.2187 4523714.5334, 14133648.7514 4523742.104, 14133647.6716 4523741.4992, 14133627.9028 4523732.3156, 14133602.0341 4523722.0539, 14133602.5473 4523709.1065, 14133615.2935 4523693.4445, 14133618.8451 4523694.8361, 14133631.6011 4523700.1453, 14133638.9491 4523704.4527, 14133659.6581 4523714.4871, 14133660.2187 4523714.5334)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6922,18,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14134008.7887 4520834.2569, 14134007.1838 4520847.1595, 14134009.6122 4520851.1575, 14134004.0131 4520850.6464, 14133998.0265 4520850.6065, 14133992.3305 4520849.1996, 14133982.4255 4520845.5005, 14133982.3376 4520844.8044, 14133978.0657 4520842.6132, 14133973.9832 4520839.8022, 14133973.0507 4520839.8523, 14133967.8464 4520837.1043, 14133966.6922 4520835.7254, 14133963.9822 4520810.7539, 14133971.394 4520819.6899, 14133978.6385 4520826.3244, 14133984.3592 4520829.3388, 14133989.9548 4520830.5684, 14134008.7887 4520834.2569)), ((14134239.083 4520811.4953, 14134235.7487 4520812.2095, 14134228.2493 4520813.0298, 14134187.887 4520821.1104, 14134190.1595 4520802.8403, 14134205.8448 4520800.9354, 14134210.811 4520799.4817, 14134219.6458 4520798.7505, 14134240.5875 4520794.2322, 14134241.1255 4520795.0751, 14134239.083 4520811.4953)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6923,19,보행어린이사고,20401000,5,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14139281.6152 4519814.3426, 14139281.5786 4519815.0892, 14139279.3187 4519814.695, 14139281.6152 4519814.3426)), ((14139265.6559 4519804.7217, 14139272.7207 4519813.544, 14139245.12 4519808.7294, 14139226.2922 4519805.9103, 14139224.7143 4519806.0217, 14139220.4943 4519799.0738, 14139220.4938 4519797.2804, 14139265.6559 4519804.7217)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6924,20,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"POLYGON((14135923.5445 4520082.8251, 14135920.3168 4520092.5317, 14135916.7001 4520091.3667, 14135887.1483 4520087.5145, 14135867.2622 4520085.7143, 14135861.7945 4520085.6271, 14135856.2929 4520081.7841, 14135852.2574 4520077.2676, 14135853.691 4520076.4861, 14135887.9687 4520080.9844, 14135913.198 4520083.3804, 14135920.0661 4520084.4191, 14135922.7883 4520083.711, 14135923.5445 4520082.8251))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6925,21,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14135425.588 4520419.4907, 14135432.0601 4520424.4695, 14135447.9745 4520437.7345, 14135414.9611 4520435.0818, 14135354.8 4520412.989, 14135348.9406 4520385.1424, 14135342.2036 4520360.3604, 14135331.6518 4520316.7837, 14135329.8582 4520310.0186, 14135360.9401 4520348.833, 14135387.6805 4520364.5519, 14135395.0399 4520392.2142, 14135395.8587 4520393.9482, 14135403.0781 4520403.8847, 14135421.6266 4520416.4433, 14135425.5328 4520419.5322, 14135425.588 4520419.4907)), ((14135531.7778 4520398.0131, 14135525.549 4520414.8443, 14135522.9854 4520426.1139, 14135516.2589 4520428.1391, 14135521.8698 4520410.1735, 14135521.3287 4520405.8577, 14135534.3029 4520375.1946, 14135542.006 4520360.5911, 14135545.6876 4520352.4667, 14135551.9173 4520340.7399, 14135574.077 4520314.382, 14135571.3023 4520320.2369, 14135563.9017 4520334.4228, 14135549.1139 4520360.4912, 14135540.1627 4520378.132, 14135531.7778 4520398.0131)), ((14135608.6294 4520262.6217, 14135608.1254 4520261.8623, 14135597.2597 4520273.6555, 14135594.1591 4520276.2619, 14135586.4694 4520288.233, 14135585.4084 4520290.4717, 14135590.82 4520271.5206, 14135592.4967 4520269.7311, 14135605.6695 4520253.4075, 14135605.7706 4520251.8511, 14135600.9975 4520234.7901, 14135602.2451 4520234.4359, 14135597.132 4520216.3371, 14135594.7257 4520211.3755, 14135594.4359 4520211.0718, 14135589.7363 4520213.2802, 14135580.7719 4520192.0064, 14135581.2224 4520177.4427, 14135587.4481 4520177.6465, 14135587.6144 4520163.9275, 14135588.248 4520144.9061, 14135588.0095 4520140.4006, 14135586.1353 4520122.2645, 14135583.7312 4520107.0014, 14135583.2505 4520102.2238, 14135592.3449 4520112.7797, 14135592.8023 4520120.4689, 14135594.5636 4520135.7066, 14135594.1131 4520185.1651, 14135606.5899 4520184.2943, 14135635.4875 4520182.5786, 14135640.46 4520182.1185, 14135642.1887 4520196.8289, 14135628.2509 4520198.0299, 14135617.0847 4520200.5717, 14135616.8324 4520202.0777, 14135617.9024 4520207.368, 14135619.5661 4520207.6466, 14135643.2713 4520206.041, 14135644.6347 4520217.6431, 14135626.3568 4520217.6841, 14135603.6097 4520216.5155, 14135608.5969 4520233.9309, 14135614.9952 4520253.5485, 14135608.6294 4520262.6217)), ((14135337.8457 4520167.9872, 14135312.2316 4520234.6241, 14135321.6583 4520279.0903, 14135317.1959 4520262.2589, 14135316.2132 4520260.3095, 14135312.584 4520259.0686, 14135292.7599 4520260.0134, 14135291.2937 4520222.0834, 14135289.2211 4520191.3547, 14135297.287 4520189.8124, 14135291.3058 4520166.4614, 14135288.678 4520150.3633, 14135306.5129 4520118.3973, 14135328.3299 4520099.6008, 14135330.2646 4520144.6133, 14135335.9103 4520145.0574, 14135337.2811 4520158.0551, 14135335.542 4520158.8522, 14135337.8457 4520167.9872)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6926,45,보행어린이사고,20401000,2,11,11110,"MULTIPOLYGON(((14133299.9319 4523353.0095, 14133300.0966 4523359.0739, 14133301.1013 4523367.936, 14133294.2179 4523368.718, 14133292.8626 4523353.678, 14133293.6068 4523348.3892, 14133299.9319 4523353.0095)), ((14133429.9959 4523361.7879, 14133426.0683 4523366.803, 14133424.341 4523365.6059, 14133410.7182 4523354.0042, 14133404.857 4523352.913, 14133393.9754 4523358.4664, 14133378.6063 4523363.8532, 14133372.1013 4523364.2304, 14133369.7961 4523359.6085, 14133380.5502 4523357.524, 14133384.9127 4523355.9688, 14133401.2536 4523347.6581, 14133404.0026 4523345.2284, 14133408.0154 4523335.419, 14133408.3586 4523328.4816, 14133408.1216 4523321.9112, 14133406.4753 4523314.4572, 14133419.7867 4523296.2345, 14133419.8343 4523295.8514, 14133436.6877 4523288.9066, 14133447.5429 4523285.3409, 14133451.4133 4523284.836, 14133451.1209 4523291.0645, 14133448.8641 4523291.4434, 14133438.8536 4523294.8574, 14133417.6467 4523303.2043, 14133415.0868 4523304.8995, 14133414.7441 4523311.052, 14133415.3478 4523314.8753, 14133417.01 4523319.1171, 14133416.2638 4523325.1046, 14133414.308 4523329.9904, 14133413.8003 4523338.6242, 14133415.6269 4523342.1947, 14133421.083 4523348.0329, 14133424.2966 4523350.5537, 14133426.6159 4523351.3266, 14133429.7296 4523351.252, 14133432.4275 4523350.7341, 14133435.025 4523349.4692, 14133445.3015 4523342.2445, 14133435.2662 4523355.0584, 14133434.72 4523355.2417, 14133431.0643 4523355.4175, 14133423.0975 4523354.5029, 14133417.4004 4523352.222, 14133426.8017 4523359.2769, 14133429.9959 4523361.7879)), ((14133257.048 4523320.632, 14133257.0367 4523320.6344, 14133257.0074 4523320.5349, 14133257.048 4523320.632)), ((14133468.1233 4523230.8161, 14133464.7833 4523233.6337, 14133464.552 4523244.85, 14133465.8961 4523256.6239, 14133465.0128 4523258.8516, 14133465.0626 4523260.6365, 14133460.0583 4523260.0207, 14133460.6184 4523246.0004, 14133459.989 4523243.3544, 14133437.2983 4523242.8642, 14133426.8212 4523246.6074, 14133418.7109 4523248.1317, 14133416.2346 4523239.4708, 14133416.9656 4523240.0585, 14133426.6598 4523240.1382, 14133430.8459 4523237.6461, 14133458.5164 4523237.9735, 14133460.547 4523235.2398, 14133460.8659 4523225.5177, 14133452.2739 4523211.6267, 14133426.5595 4523175.1828, 14133422.1217 4523176.1938, 14133399.7735 4523201.9215, 14133396.9864 4523205.1737, 14133405.68 4523216.2543, 14133407.9982 4523220.178, 14133386.4246 4523193.2076, 14133387.8261 4523194.3209, 14133389.7041 4523194.8028, 14133390.9401 4523193.2335, 14133390.3736 4523191.651, 14133379.3341 4523182.8228, 14133378.0184 4523182.6985, 14133377.8576 4523182.4976, 14133381.8071 4523177.5195, 14133382.3234 4523179.0642, 14133393.3627 4523187.8795, 14133395.0267 4523188.0828, 14133414.286 4523162.7464, 14133415.9133 4523160.1773, 14133414.1494 4523157.9107, 14133400.9158 4523150.7654, 14133401.567 4523149.0855, 14133427.6137 4523165.3998, 14133427.1933 4523166.1949, 14133427.2055 4523167.3218, 14133442.64 4523186.9499, 14133444.0131 4523188.7852, 14133468.3752 4523227.6807, 14133468.1233 4523230.8161)))"
A2SM_TFCACDHSPOT.fid--1a2e5595_1720e769346_6927,46,보행어린이사고,20401000,1,11,11110,"POLYGON((14133966.8626 4520837.296, 14133962.8552 4520838.0769, 14133941.2888 4520844.98, 14133939.7914 4520838.2968, 14133952.4203 4520836.4026, 14133959.1135 4520834.4812, 14133960.916 4520832.8997, 14133962.0386 4520830.3561, 14133966.6969 4520835.7687, 14133966.8626 4520837.296))"
```

Comment: Try adding `IGNORE 1 LINES` so the load ignores the line with just column titles in

Comment: ... and you may load the data for first 7 columns immediately, without intermediate variables.

Comment: I am no expert, but will `ST_PolygonFromText(@col8)` cope with the lines that use `MULTIPOLYGON`